# Add new filetype syntax to markdown code fence

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

For work I use a certain SQL-like DSL. We'll call it `lang`. I write my docs in vim(wiki), and these docs contain a lot of `lang` snippets. I have written my simple syntax highlight rules for `lang`, and they are contained within a `lang-syntax.vim` script.

For pure `lang` files, (which I call `something.lang`), it is really easy to write an `autocmd` that sources the `lang-syntax.vim` when `.lang` file is opened.

However, I can't figure out how to do this for markdown code blocks. For example, if I have this kind of code block in my vimwiki:

````
```lang
lang code
```
````

I don't have a clue how to make markdown source the `lang-syntax.vim` script only for the code block.

Comment: The vim markdown syntax plugin supports including other languages, this is shown here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown?tab=readme-ov-file#vim-markdown-runtime-files

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm using vimwiki for highlighting

Comment: don't know what vimwiki is using for markdown highlighting

Comment: The syntax can be made to change automatically if you set a filetype using a ftdetect script

Comment: I believe the following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10813/23502) should help you to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: You could be interested by the following @IngoKarkat plugin [SyntaxRange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt the answer you linked is precisely what I need. Please add the answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll propose to link your question as duplicated such that other are directed to the answer I point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10813/23502) that explain how to have C section within an Haskell program.

Remark: You could also be interested by the @IngoKarkat [SyntaxRange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange) plugin.